# Quasi-interior points of a sublattice

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-lattices

Let $1\leq p< \infty$ and $E= L^p(\Omega,\mu)$. If $A \subseteq \Omega$ is a measurable set and $T: E \to E$ is defined by $Tf=\mathbf{1}_Af$, then find the quasi-interior points of $\operatorname{Im} T$.

**Attempt**: Of course as $T$ is a positive operator, so $\operatorname{Im} T$ is a Banach lattice. I was able to show that $f$ is a quasi-interior point of $E$ if and only if $f(x) >0$ for almost all $x$.

However, I don't think that if $f \in \operatorname{Im} T$ is a quasi-interior point of $\operatorname{Im} T$, then it must be a quasi-interior point of $E$ too. Are quasi-interior point of $\operatorname{Im} T$ just all $f\in \operatorname{Im} T$ such that $f(x)=0$ for almost all $x \in A$?

Comment: A few remarks: (i) The first sentence in the description of your **Attempt** claimes that the image of a positive operator on a Banach lattice is always a Banach lattice, too. This is not correct - the image of a positive operator need not even be closed. (ii) Your characterization of quasi-interior points of $E$ is correct if $(\Omega,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite. (But there are non-$\sigma$-finite measure spaces where this is not true.) [to be continued]

Comment: [continuation] (iii) Concerning your sentence "However, I don't think that..." Your observation is not only correct, but even more is true: if $(\Omega,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite and $\Omega \setminus A$ has non-zero measure, then the image of $T$ cannot contain any quasi-interior point of $E$ at all. This follows immediately from the characterization of quasi-interior points of $E$  that you have mentioned. [to be continued]

Comment: [continuation] (iv) I can't follow your last sentence. If $(\Omega,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, the quasi-interior points of the image of $T$ are simply the functions $f$ in $E$ which are $>0$ almost everywhere on $A$ and $=0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega \setminus A$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes, I worded it incorrectly. That's what I meant in my last sentence. Thanks, its much clearer now.